# C# display / (forward slash) in MaskedTextBox

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

I noticed that when the mask defined for input in a MaskedTextBox contains "/", it is automatically substituted by "-" in the textbox.
I tried this using the default Date format available in VS, which in the form's Designer results in the following code

```
this.maskedTextBox2.Name = "maskedTextBox2";
this.maskedTextBox2.Mask = "00/00/0000";
this.maskedTextBox2.ValidatingType = typeof(System.DateTime);
```

and also for another MaskedTextBox by defining my custom mask in the form's constructor like this

```
InitializeComponent();
this.maskedTextBox1.Mask = @"00/00/0000";
```

In both cases the prompt displayed in the text boxes looks like this

```
__-__-____
```

Is there a way to actually display slashes there, instead of dashes?
Marek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask?view=net-5.0), a slash is a 'date separator' and therefore I'm guessing that your system currently runs in a locale where a date separator is a dash.

> / Date separator. The actual display character used will be the date symbol appropriate to the format provider, as determined by the control's FormatProvider property.

If you really DO want a forward slash then "00\/00\/00" should do the trick (but then it's not really a compliant date input).